# Multiple Pull calls to same Subscription at same time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

While getting the notifications from a particular topic using pull method, is it possible to make a pull call to same subscription through different servers at same time? If not, what if I call pull using various thread on same server at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call mutilple pull from a subscription, each pull will return different message. If you want to pull the same messages, create multiple subscriptions for the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to make multiple pull calls on the same subscription at the same time, either from different servers or from the same server. In fact, if your subscriber can handle the messages, you are encouraged to make multiple pull calls simultaneously from the same server in order to maximize throughput.

When you have multiple servers pulling from the same subscription, you are load balancing the processing of the messages over those servers. If you want each server to receive the full set of all messages published to the topic, then you should create separate subscriptions for each server.